# findOneBy() - Sanitize email input - mongodb-odm 2.x

Tags: php, mongodb

Is this safe (from an SQL injection perspective) to do:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$user = $dm->getRepository(self::$repository)->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
```

Best

**edit;-**

So, the string `'user@gmail.com'` comes into my method via a variable `$email`.

Comment: Might want to add more context, if the 'email' value is hardcoded, its safe, but if it should be a $variable later on, you need to sanitize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are safe from SQL injection because the MongoDB drivers do not speak SQL.

But beyond this, unless you use `db.runCommand`, there is no way to change a "find" statement (`find`,`find_one`, etc.) into an "update" or "delete" statement.  No amount of variable substitution or trickery will change the basic behavior from read to anything else.  In contrast, the classic `cursor.execute("A SQL string")` can do almost *anything* including adding/removing users and tables, etc. etc. and must be very carefully sanitized.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Always pays to ask.

Comment: So what you're actually saying is SQL injection is ONLY associated with update & delete queries.

Comment: He's saying that SQL injection is only associated with SQL.